# Saving data in the Application scope in Android

Tags: android

I am building an application in Android with **multiple activities**. I have a list of an object of type `TodoItem` that I get from a collection in *Firestore database*, and I need to access the list from **more than one** activity to make changes and updates to the list.

To do that, I thought about saving the list in the **Application scope** (is it a good idea?). For this reason, I created a `class MyApplication extends Application` (and added it to the Manifest file).

Instead of just adding the list as a *class field* of `MyApplication` I thought that maybe I should create a class named `DataManager` that will hold application-wide information such as my list of `TodoItem`s (and here I ask again: is it a good idea? or maybe there is a better solution?).

At this point I am trying to decide what is a better approach to create and save the `DataManager` class:

- One idea is to make `DataManager` a **Singleton** class and save it as a **class field** of `MyApplication`. This way, the activities will be able to get the instance of the class using `DataManager.getInstance()` without the need to get it from the application class with a *getter* method. In this approach, I will have to create the instance of `DataManager` and init the field of the application with it in the `OnCreate()` method of the application.
- The second idea is to make it a **non-singleton**, add `DataManager` field to `MyApplication`, and create a getter named `getDataManager()` in the application class. The getter will check if the field is `null` (i.e. already initialized or not) and will create a new instance correspondingly. This way, the activities will get the instance using `((MyApplication) getApplication()).getDataManager()`.

I would like to hear what do you think about my approaches to solve the problem, and if you have any other suggestions or other ways to improve my suggested design.

Comment: `I thought about saving the list in the Application scope` all of this was probably good 10 years ago, but this isn't modern android development anymore. use a single activity with fragments, save the data you need in your single activity and access it as you need it. if you're set on using activities, then yes, just do this, probably doesn't make enough of a difference for you to worry about this

Comment: @a_local_nobody Thanks for your response! So far I have learned about using multiple activities in the course that I am taking at the university. I understand from your response that it is an old way to write an application. As for my post, I would still like to know what sounds like a better approach to solve the problem with the old design. As for the new design of single activity, the solution will be to use a ViewModel?

Comment: well, "better" or "best" is quite difficult, all solutions have pros and cons so you can't really find a perfect answer here, perhaps you could consider saving the data into a local database (Room) and then having it be your single source of truth, read data, store in room, read from room wherever you go. viewmodels would help you achieve a bit of an architecture but it wouldn't really help you much with getting data to where you need it. all of this being said, if you're just being taught to write an app with activities, probably just do that and get it done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice way when your data source is simple. You can create a singleton class to hold and manage data, including read and write from the singleton.
When you want to use complex data, you can store it to your device disk rather than memory. Android application support you to store your data with file, database, or key-value preference. As for your case, you can use database to store your todolist. Android support sqlite for these work, and we have official orm library called `room`.
raw sqlite: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite
room library: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room

Comment: You might also add a links to ViewModel and LiveData.